# Combinations of linear mappings

Tags: linear-algebra

*What I know:* the composition of two linear transformations, say $(M\circ L)(x)$, has the geometric interpretation of successively applying two transformations to $x$, e.g. first a rotation by $L$, then a shear by $M$.

*My question is this*: What is the geometric interpretation of

1. $(L+M)(x)$
2. $(tL)(x)$, where $t$ is some real number?

I would suppose we are simply achieving a new transformation, but I do not know how we this would be different from that defined by $(M\circ L)(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some sense, 2 is again of the form $(tI_n\circ L)(x)$, and you may regard this as first applying L, followed by the action of the linear map $tI_n$, and $tI_n$ uniformly dilates all vectors by t away from the origin. (order you perform these is immaterial in this case)

For 1, $(L+M)(x)= L(x)+M(x)$ holds, and provided that they have the same domain/codomain, then $L+M$ is just another linear transformation. You can simply think of it as adding the images under M and L together.